# How to use EventListener in .net core 2.2 (Runtime Events)

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.2

MS announce the release of .NET Core 2.2. It includes diagnostic improvements to the runtime, with `Runtime Events`, My question is: How to use EventListener in .NET Core 2.2? The article is poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got it working in a sample ASP.Net Core 2.2 API project. It's actually fairly easy but I also needed some time.

I have created a diagnostics class like the one mentioned in the documentation. I named that class `Diagnostics.cs`. That class contains the code from the Microsoft documentation. Nothing more, nothing less. 
I than added it as a singleton service in ConfigureServices().

```
services.AddSingleton<Diagnostics>();
```

Finally I injected it in the ValuesController.

```
private Diagnostics _diag;
        public ValuesController(Diagnostics diag)
        {
            _diag = diag;
        }
```

When hitting the endpoint from Postman I got a lot of events.

```
ThreadID = 13588 ID = 192 Name = MethodJitInliningFailed
        Name = "MethodBeingCompiledNamespace" Value = "Microsoft.IntelliTrace.TelemetryObserver.MvcActionEventArgumentSerializer"
        Name = "MethodBeingCompiledName" Value = "SerializeArguments"
        Name = "MethodBeingCompiledNameSignature" Value = "class System.String  (class System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<value class System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<class System.String,class System.Object>>)"
        Name = "InlinerNamespace" Value = "Microsoft.IntelliTrace.TelemetryObserver.MvcActionEventArgumentSerializer"
        Name = "InlinerName" Value = "SerializeArguments"
        Name = "InlinerNameSignature" Value = "class System.String  (class System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<value class System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<class System.String,class System.Object>>)"
        Name = "InlineeNamespace" Value = "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.__Canon,System.__Canon]]"
        Name = "InlineeName" Value = "get_Current"
        Name = "InlineeNameSignature" Value = "instance !0  ()"
        Name = "FailAlways" Value = "False"
        Name = "FailReason" Value = "target not direct"
        Name = "ClrInstanceID" Value = "8"
```

That's of course only for test purposes. I would probably not add this as singleton but try to make it generic / typed instead and add it as a scoped or transient service.

Comment: Thanks Dan, the link  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-2-2  say :These events describe the behavior of GC, JIT, ThreadPool, and interop. Now I want to get runtime info about these，Can you describe it more clearly?

Comment: Well if you do what I described in the answer, you will see exactly this type of information: GC, JIT, Threadpool. I have also written a blog post. Maybe it would be more clear: http://danpatrascu.com/asp-net-core-2-2-runtime-events/